# Iterate over the childred of a tag

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var thead = document.getElementById("my_table").getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];

// =>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th ....
    <th ....
    <th ....
```

Now how can I select or find "`th`" by index? 
`thead.children[0]` returns the whole "tr", `thead.children[0][0]` is undefined. How can I reach "th" nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use element's `children` property to access element's children:

```
var thead = document.getElementById("my_table").getElementsByTagName("thead")[0].children[0].children;
```

which means

> In `my_table` find the `thead` tag, get its first children (`tr`) and return the *array* of its children

Now, you will be able to iterate through them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < thead.length; i++)
{
    console.log(thead[i]);
}
```

The more convenient way is to use `querySelectorAll` and CSS selectors:

```
var thead = document.querySelectorAll('#my_table > thead > tr > th');
for (var i = 0; i < thead.length; i++)
{
    console.log(thead[i]);
}
```

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/f0s6v28v/1/).

Comment: in the 1st case as I said "thead.length" is 1 because it returns the whole "tr" tag. How can I access its children?